# How can I calculate the intersection of a line and the geoid (EGM96)?

Tags: intersection, line, geoid

I have a known line (point and vector) described in ECEF [(Earth-Centered, Earth-Fixed)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF) coordinates and I need to find where it intersects the geoid [(Earth Gravitational Model 1996)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EGM96).  Is there existing software I can use to do this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. I added some links to help clarify. I think it shouldn't be 'on hold'.

Comment: Thanks Martin.  Hopefully Mapparez will reopen the question.  I know it looks a little bare bones, but I think that is all the information I need to ask the question...I'm sure the answer is more complicated though.  I know that computing the intersection of a line and the WGS84 ellipsoid is fairly easy...I believe this is the same problem but with a much more complicated surface.